# MariaDB and MySQL differ in handling date field while compare to a string

Tags: mysql, date, mariadb

I have the following enviroment:

on the side A: `MySQLDB 5.5.28`
on the side B: `MariaDB 5.5.33`

Both sides serve the same database in structure and content, `MySQL` is the mother and a simple mysqldump fills the `MariaDB`.

I have a table with a "`date`" column and some other content.

When I do a

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE datecolumn >= '2013';
```

The result differs between `MariaDB` and `MySQLDB`:

`MySQLDB` gives a set with all the data which has a date bigger than `01-01-2013`,
`MariaDB` give the complete data of the table, which means for me it handles the '`2013`' as a '`0`'.

I don't like the statement at all, but it is customer-code which I do not want to alter.

Is this a known behavior? I searched for it but find not this exact problem but some other things around the handling of '`date`'.

Comment: You may want to confirm that the table structures are exactly the same, but I think this might be a compatibility issue caused by MariaDB now being stricter on dates (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/ )

Comment: "`MariaDB` does more strict checking of `date`, `datetime` and `timestamp` values. For example `UNIX_TIMESTAMP('x')` now returns `NULL` instead of `0`.". [Incompatibilities between MariaDB 5.3 and MySQL 5.1 and MariaDB 5.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/#incompatibilities-between-mariadb-53-and-mysql-51-and-mariadb-52)

Comment: I don't think the "more strict checking" applies since if it converted `'2013'` to NULL, it would return 0 rows. Seems like a bug?

Comment: Of course I found that "...more strict checking..." before but I am afraid this is not just a strict behavior but a problem for a switch to MariaDB. A syntax error or somthing like that would be more helpful than just interpreting a numeric string as a numeric 0. This is not what I expect when I read "more strict checking".